# Nested SQL Query (Query a subset of data)

Tags: sql-server

Assume I have the following structure...

```
Structures
- ID
- Name

Fields
- ID
- StructureID
- Key
```

These table hold simplistic 'structures' (Think very simplistic tables).

There is then an additional table

```
DataValues
- ID
- FieldID 
- Value
- RowID
```

Example data inside of the table...

```
ID | FieldID | Value             | RowID
1  | 5       | Blog Post Title   | 1
2  | 6       | Blog Post Body    | 1
3  | 5       | Another Post H1   | 2
4  | 6       | Another Body      | 2
```

Now I want the ability to do dynamic queries to each data set, so grab all the RowID's that follow a certain pattern.

```
SELECT DV.RowID FROM DataValues as DV 
    INNER JOIN Fields as F ON DV.FieldID = F.ID 
    INNER JOIN DataRows as DR ON DV.RowID = DR.ID 
WHERE DR.StructureID = 2 
AND (F.[Key] = 'Title' AND DV.[Value] = 'Blog Post Title')
```

The issue is then when we want to do multiple conditions

```
SELECT DV.RowID FROM DataValues as DV 
    INNER JOIN Fields as F ON DV.FieldID = F.ID 
    INNER JOIN DataRows as DR ON DV.RowID = DR.ID 
WHERE DR.StructureID = 2 
AND (F.[Key] = 'Title' AND DV.[Value] = 'Blog Post Title') 
AND (F.[Key] = 'Body' AND DV.[Value] <> 'A Body We Dont Want')
```

This obviously wont work, is there a way to query a subset of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you mean correctly (and I'm not sure I do), you should return 2 rows per RowID for a 'matching' result.

Therefore you can do an `OR` on the key data you are searching for, `GROUP BY RowID` and count that there are matching results for each subset.

```
SELECT 
  DV.RowID,
  MIN(CASE 
        WHEN F.[Key] = 'Title' THEN 1 
        WHEN F.[Key] = 'Body' THEN 2
      END
    ) AS Ordinal 
FROM DataValues as DV,
INNER JOIN Fields as F ON DV.FieldID = F.ID 
INNER JOIN DataRows as DR ON DV.RowID = DR.ID 
WHERE DR.StructureID = 2 
AND (
     (F.[Key] = 'Title' AND DV.[Value] = 'Blog Post Title') 
OR   (F.[Key] = 'Body' AND DV.[Value] <> 'A Body We Dont Want') 
    )
GROUP BY DV.RowID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY Ordinal ASC;
```

Alternatively, you could do an `INTERSECT` of the two result sets for all of the `RowID` values that satisfy both conditions:

```
SELECT DV.RowID, 1 as Ordinal 
FROM DataValues as DV 
INNER JOIN Fields as F ON DV.FieldID = F.ID 
INNER JOIN DataRows as DR ON DV.RowID = DR.ID 
WHERE DR.StructureID = 2 
  AND (F.[Key] = 'Title' AND DV.[Value] = 'Blog Post Title') 
INTERSECT
SELECT DV.RowID, 2 AS Ordinal
FROM DataValues as DV 
INNER JOIN Fields as F ON DV.FieldID = F.ID 
INNER JOIN DataRows as DR ON DV.RowID = DR.ID 
WHERE DR.StructureID = 2 
  AND (F.[Key] = 'Body' AND DV.[Value] <> 'A Body We Dont Want')
ORDER BY Ordinal ASC;
```

Comment: Is it possible to order the results based on one of the keys values?

Comment: @LiamB Check updated answer for a general idea